# Printing tree with SQL CTE

Tags: sql-server, tree, common-table-expression

The schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [Structure](
    [StructureId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [SequenceNumber] [int] NOT NULL, -- order for siblings, unique per parent
    [ParentStructureId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [Structure_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [StructureId] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [Structure]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Structure_FK1] 
FOREIGN KEY([ParentStructureId])
REFERENCES [Structure] ([StructureId])
```

Currently, I can get all the logical data out with the follow CTE, but I would like to print it directly in a depth first fashion.

```
WITH SCTE (StructureId, Level, Seq, ParentId)
AS
(
  SELECT StructureId,  0, SequenceNumber, [ParentStructureId]
    FROM Structure
    WHERE [ParentStructureId] IS NULL 
          AND StructureId = 'F6C5F016-1270-47C1-972F-349C32DFC92A'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT Structure.StructureId, Level + 1, SequenceNumber, ParentStructureId
  FROM Structure
  INNER JOIN SCTE ON SCTE.StructureId = Structure.ParentStructureId
)

SELECT * FROM SCTE
ORDER BY Level, ParentId, Seq
```

The output is as follows (truncated here):

```
StructureId                     Level   Seq ParentId
F6C5F016-1270-47C1-972F-349C32DFC92A    0   0   NULL
D2E34429-401A-4A49-9E18-E81CCA0FB417    1   0   F6C5F016-1270-47C1-972F-349C32DFC92A
0CC5E16C-9194-40CA-9F72-1CED2972D7CA    1   1   F6C5F016-1270-47C1-972F-349C32DFC92A
1ECD1D30-EB85-42B0-969F-75794343E3B4    1   2   F6C5F016-1270-47C1-972F-349C32DFC92A
EEC3A981-B790-4600-8CD1-F15972CD9230    2   0   0CC5E16C-9194-40CA-9F72-1CED2972D7CA
4406F639-2F58-4918-A9EF-A4B0F379BEA0    2   1   0CC5E16C-9194-40CA-9F72-1CED2972D7CA
FCAF7870-C606-4AA6-85EE-57B90B1B0CC3    2   2   0CC5E16C-9194-40CA-9F72-1CED2972D7CA
855DF5FB-1593-4E5B-8EF9-3770B45F89D6    2   3   0CC5E16C-9194-40CA-9F72-1CED2972D7CA
3D16DF32-C04F-49B4-B0D9-5BDC9104F810    2   4   0CC5E16C-9194-40CA-9F72-1CED2972D7CA
A1084D00-0198-47D9-87E0-BB8234233F14    2   5   0CC5E16C-9194-40CA-9F72-1CED2972D7CA
CE443C0D-376F-46EC-9914-32C6B7200DB1    2   6   0CC5E16C-9194-40CA-9F72-1CED2972D7CA
0DEA587D-4FCF-414C-AD71-FB00829F8082    2   7   0CC5E16C-9194-40CA-9F72-1CED2972D7CA
CC9FC8D3-254A-486B-8DC4-07E57627476C    2   0   1ECD1D30-EB85-42B0-969F-75794343E3B4
215565CC-501F-4850-B8AE-5466DA5E6854    2   1   1ECD1D30-EB85-42B0-969F-75794343E3B4
D4E6C8E5-5ADD-4AD1-B59B-1A672F66888A    2   2   1ECD1D30-EB85-42B0-969F-75794343E3B4
796C65BF-4714-4DBF-A97A-2150DBE3098C    2   3   1ECD1D30-EB85-42B0-969F-75794343E3B4
B39DEB9C-BE42-43B4-9C38-968399D7D1E2    2   4   1ECD1D30-EB85-42B0-969F-75794343E3B4
6C2F70C6-1DA0-4E1A-BBC1-D7FCAFE6AFEE    2   0   D2E34429-401A-4A49-9E18-E81CCA0FB417
75D7B43B-C971-46B4-BC42-58C3605ADD79    2   1   D2E34429-401A-4A49-9E18-E81CCA0FB417
0B5AAAA0-A69F-431E-86BA-148444D7B1E6    2   2   D2E34429-401A-4A49-9E18-E81CCA0FB417
CB3CF66B-D83A-45E2-953A-6F0CEE094F5B    2   3   D2E34429-401A-4A49-9E18-E81CCA0FB417
1D5F69C3-F036-4667-BD75-A0DC1506DB6D    2   4   D2E34429-401A-4A49-9E18-E81CCA0FB417
71B894F7-B9FC-44DE-AEDB-E6FA026A6082    2   5   D2E34429-401A-4A49-9E18-E81CCA0FB417
F1DFA1E1-013B-449C-9D9D-14C64E75D418    2   6   D2E34429-401A-4A49-9E18-E81CCA0FB417
```

As you can see, the result is 'breadth first' which makes printing a tree kinda impossible as it is now.

Is there any way (there probably is a trivial way, but my SQL skills are extremely poor) to get the resultant list in 'tree printing friendly' format?

I know I could just dump the results into a program and code the output, but as an exercise I would prefer doing this in SQL itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Edited after comment.  You could add the path to a node, and order on that:

```
declare @t table (id int, parent int)
insert @t (id, parent) values (1, null), (2,1), (3,2), (4,3), (5,null), (6,5)

; with cte as (
    select  id, parent
    ,       cast(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',12) + 
                 CONVERT(varchar(12),id),12) as varchar(max)) Path
    from    @t
    where   parent is null
    union all
    select  child.id, child.parent
    ,       parent.Path + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',12) + 
                                CONVERT(varchar(12),child.id),12) as Path
    from    @t child
    join    cte parent
    on      parent.id = child.parent
)
select  *
from    cte
order by
        Path
```

This prints the root first, followed by leaves in order.  If your id can be larger than 12 digits, increase the number in the `char(x)` casts.

Comment: I dont want the deepest printing first. The root must print first, like a tree. I just want to get all the branches in depth first ascending order, so it can be printed easily without further processing.

Comment: Thanks, the path idea might work  :) Will try it. Edit: Not sure if it will work due to string ordering. Does SQL have a natural sort?

Comment: +1 for the path suggestion. There's a good reference here, by Jacob Sebastian: http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/jacob/archive/2008/10/05/recursive-cte-and-ordering-of-the-hierarchical-result.aspx

Comment: @lepiie: Added leading zeroes which should fix the sort

Comment: Thanks, it worked after some cursing about SQL not having a PADLEFT function, grrr!